# Google Oauth is Having a Null Error for .Net 6

Tags: c#, .net, google-oauth, asp.net-core-6.0

I'm new to Oauth2 with .Net and I am trying to get it to work. I've tried editing the Program.Cs but it hasn't worked.

Program.Cs

```
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(options => {
    options.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
})
        .AddCookie(options =>
        {
            options.LoginPath = "/users/google/login"; 
        })
        .AddGoogle(options =>
        {
            options.ClientId = builder.Configuration.GetSection("GoogleOauthSettings:ClientId").Value;
            options.ClientSecret = builder.Configuration.GetSection("GoogleOauthSettings:ClientSecret").Value;
        });
```

My Users Controller Routes. To save space I am not adding my other routes since all of those work. I am just showing my imports and google routes.

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using CalenTaskApi.Respositories;
using CalenTaskApi.Dtos;
using CalenTaskApi.Entities;
using System.Text;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cors;
using CalenTaskApi.Service;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Google;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
  
[HttpPost("google/login")]
    public IActionResult LoginWithGoogle(GoogleLoginDto googleLoginDto)
    {
        var properties = new AuthenticationProperties { RedirectUri = Url.Action("GoogleResponse") };
        return Challenge(properties, GoogleDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);

    }

    [HttpPost("google/response")]
    public async Task<string> GoogleResponse()
    {
        var result = await HttpContext.AuthenticateAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);

        var claims = result.Principal.Identities
            .FirstOrDefault().Claims.Select(claim => new
        {
            claim.Issuer,
            claim.OriginalIssuer,
            claim.Type,
            claim.Value
        });
        var claimsJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(claims);

        return claimsJson;
    }
```

C# is telling me that the google/response router in my var claims the result.Principal.Indentities is returning null.